# Is there an established method to weigh a weighted mean?

Tags: algorithm, weighted-average

**Problem.** The weighted mean/average can be used to give differing weight in a mean computation to elements of differing importance. I need to figure out an extension that would in turn 'scale' or 'weigh' the resulting weighted mean with regards to zero, depending on the actual (non-normalized) values of the weights:

- if the weights are low, the scaled weighted mean should be close to 0.
- if at least some weights are close to the max weight, then the scaled weighted mean should be more or less equivalent with simple weighted mean.

**Rationale and details.** I need such an extension in order to produce a more sensible mean value in a case where:

- the weights are proximity/similarity scores (of interval (0,1)) of the elements (let's call them neighbors for simplicity) of a target element, in some space, and
- the values on the neighbors (being averaged) reflect a change in some quality of theirs (because it is assumed to have an effect on the target, if they are close enough)
- elements that are further away should have less weight, so using weighted mean seems reasonable - but in some cases, *all* the neighbors are far away - in these cases, they presumably should have little to no effect on the target (so their mean should reflect this, and be closer to zero).

**Reproducible example**. This requirement is not met when using a simple weighted means:

```
#  Using R for example code (answer doesn't have to use R)
weighted.mean = function(x, w){
 return( sum(x*w)/sum(w) )   # standard way to calculate weighted mean
}  

# Example data:
weights1 = c(0.9, 0.1, 0.01) # proximity of neighbors to target
weights2 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.01) # proximity of neighbors to some other target
values   = c(1,2,10)         # values on these neighbors

mean(values)
 # 4.333333   # not useful, doesn't take into account distance of elements at all
weighted.mean(values, weights1)
 # 1.188119   # useful result, reflects distance/weight!
weighted.mean(values, weights2)
 # 1.904762   # not useful result - none of them should have any effect, being all distant; the mean should be close to 0 (no effect) instead
```

**What I've tried so far (1)** Removing the normalizing `sum(weights)` business and just taking mean of values*weights:

```
weighted.mean2 = function(x, w){
 return( mean(x*w)      )
}  

weighted.mean2(values, weights1)
 # 0.4         # lower value, but should be viewed relatively in comparison now
weighted.mean2(values, weights2)
 # 0.1333333   # makes more sense, low proximity leads to low(er) mean value
```

**What I've tried so far (2)** Call weighted mean on 0 and the weighted mean, with the new weights for this vector of length two being 1 (max proximity/identity) and the proximity of the closest neighbor as a scale; the reasoning being that if the target has no close neighbors, then the effect in question should be about 0:

```
weighted.mean3 = function(x, w){
 tmp = weighted.mean(x, w)
 maxw = max(w)
 return( weighted.mean( c(0, tmp), c(1, maxw)) )
}  

weighted.mean3(values, weights1)
 # 0.5627931
weighted.mean3(values, weights2)
 # 0.1731602  # also makes sense, low proximity leads to low(er) mean value
```

Both approaches seem to yield a smaller value for the target with distant neighbors, and a comparatively higher value to a target with closer neighbors. However, this feels rather hacky to me, and I'm not sure if there might be cases where either approach might fail - surely there must be a more principled/established algorithm to do something like this out there (perhaps it's not called 'mean' or 'average' though; also, if one of my attempts is equivalent with one, then the answer could just confirm that). Long story short:

**Is there an established/published method to weigh/scale a weighted mean in the way I've described above?**

*Note on previous version of the question: it was initially flagged as too broad, so I rewrote it and applied to reopen, but it was auto-closed as being abandoned; so I rewrote a new question; this one also now has a clear yes or no answer (rationale and/or references beyond a simple yes/no are of course appreciated)*